# Hyperlinking in Lightning:Datatable

Tags: lightning, aura, url, datatable, lightning-datatable

Currently when I use the lightning:datatable and then a column of type url. 
I cant seem to bind a actual event to the url.. 
My Code is currently as follows

Component

```
     <lightning:layoutItem size="12" >
            <lightning:datatable data="{! v.data }" title="{!v.title}"  
                                 columns="{! v.columns }" 
                                 keyField="{!v.keyField}"
                                 minColumnWidth="{!v.minColumnWidth}"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="{v.hideCheckboxColumn}"
                                 resizeColumnDisabled="true"

                                 />
    </lightning:layoutItem>
```

Columns

```
var columns =  [
       // { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }, 
        {label: 'Client Name'
         , fieldName: 'link'
         , type: 'url' 
         , typeAttributes: {
            label: { 
                fieldName: 'Name' 
            }
        }}
      ] ; 

    component.set("v.columns" , columns ) ;
```

Rendering this out then doesnt seem to take any affect on the href

and only seems to affect the title attribute ..

[image]

[image]

Then in the docs can only see these two attributes available for a url

> url
>   Displays a URL using lightning:formattedUrl
>   label, target

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like the `Formatting with Data Types` link is missing in the documentation. Where did you find the doc about the url type?

Comment: Hmm i found it fine Just here under "Formatting with Data Types" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm

Comment: There is also a `value` attribute: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedUrl.htm

Comment: hmmm yes I seen that but binding to that doesnt seem to do anything ... 
It seems when the formatted url is used in the datatable the attributes that are actually available are label and target

Comment: Just double checking again and binding to value like so still doesnt show any effect 
`{label: 'Client Name' , fieldName: 'link'
             , type: 'url' 
             ,initialWidth : 350 
             , typeAttributes: {
                label: { 
                    fieldName: 'Name' 
                }, value: { 
                    fieldName: 'link' 
                }
         }},  `

Comment: @MartinLezer
I should of said i was doing this in a community... 
It seems when i take my example and put into its own app .. the link is populated

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me, my href correctly compiles to a salesforce id (with full regular non-lightning domain):

```
  {
    label: "SKU",
    fieldName: "Name_Link__c",
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: {
      label: { fieldName: "Name" }
    },
    initialWidth: 100
  },
```

`Name_Link__c` is:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))+Id
```

Comment: And this is working in a community is it ?

I cant seem to bind a variable to what your putting in 

`LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))+Id`

Comment: Ah, community that URL won't work, that grabs the internal. There isn't an elegant way to get Community URL in formula afaik, but it should work even hardcoded. The datatable is getting that resolved formula value, whatever it is.

Comment: I ended up logging a ticket with salesforce, and it turns out this was a spring 18 issues with lightning:formattedUrl which then also affected the lightning:datatable

Answer (score 0):

I ended up logging a ticket with salesforce, and it turns out this was a spring 18 issues with lightning:formattedUrl which then also affected the lightning:datatable

This is now going to be fixed in time for the full spring 18 release